# IE: rendering paused html5 video not-independently

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, renderer

My webpage is a long, scrolling page with html5 video at the base and elements on top of it (z-index wise). In Internet Explorer (edge), as the user scrolls the window, contents laying on top of the video outside the window does not seem to be rendered until it enters the window, and often a little bit too late; making elements 'pop up' and overlays 'painted' during scrolling.
If I hide the videos, it scrolls as I would expect (the way it works in other browsers).

According to this ugly url

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

html5 video is 'explicitly layered' for 'independent composition', if I read it correctly. That makes anything lying on top of it 'implicitly layered' for independent composition. This might explain it all.

Here is my question:
I know the videos are all paused when I scroll. Is there a way to tell internet explorer that the videos have changed to simply a static image and do not need 'independent composition' while scrolling ?

Comment: Got an upvote for the question. FYI, I ended up replacing the paused video with rendered image stills for 'roundabout' the same frame as the video was paused on, before the page started scrolling.